# Aligning the first letter of a paragraph with CSS ::first-letter Selector

Tags: css

I'd like to achieve this:

[image]

Changing the font size of the first letter is easy by using **CSS ::first-letter Selector**.
But how can I align it with the 2 or 3 lines in front of it?

Is this possible with only CSS?
If now, would appreciate any hints on how to achieve this using JS.

Comment: Can you include an [example] of what you have tried thus far?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/drop-caps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's your html markup like?
if it's just a simple

tag, this might help you

The html

```css
p:first-child:first-letter {
  float: left;
  font-size: 75px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p> a sentence for your site </p>
```

Comment: It's just a normal text inside a div.

Comment: It's working. Great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming youre using just a

tag you can use the code below that makes it so that the first letter takes up 2 lines as opposed to 1.  You can increase or decrease the number as you need to make it bigger or smaller.  You would have to add the rest of the css to this part, like changing the color if that's also what you are trying to accomplish.

```
p:first-child:first-letter {
  initial-letter: 2;
}
```

you can find a useful tutorial at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/drop-caps/